# What theory has its models exactly the boolean algebras?

Tags: logic

In Model Theory a theory defined syntactically (possibly by some grammar) has models (usually in the category of *Sets*); what theory (call it the boolean theory - for obvious reasons) has its models exactly the boolean algebras?

Answer (score 3):

You can find several equivalent sets of axioms [here](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mccune/papers/basax/v12.pdf).

Comment: A one axiom basis - that's surprising.  And the examples  aren't contrivances of multi-basis formulations - at least they don't appear to be.